# Text of option selected attribute in a drop down box

Tags: php, html

I need to send an email notification of fields in a submitted form.

My question as follows is regarding the HTML select tag in the form.

```
<select id="country_code" name="country_code">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Country</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Below I get the country code of a selected option:

```
$country_code = $_POST["country_code"];
```

How to get using PHP the text of the selected value in option tag (i.e. the country name)?

Note:
I can't use MySQL, or JavaScript, and I can't change the select box values.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767748/get-text-from-option-tag-in-php

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid JavaScript

Comment: see the other answer as well, some have used only PHP

Comment: Please read my question again , I don't want to change value of text to the value of the option tag

Comment: Without js or changing `option` values you can __do nothing__

Comment: Very poor solution is to hold an array like `['AR' => 'Argentina',]` in your script. In this case you have to sync this array with `select` values if they change.

Comment: How do I build the array if I have a list of almost 300 lines, manually?  please extend your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="country_code" name="country_code">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Country</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){ 



    $countrySelection = $_POST['country_code'];

    $countrycode_list = array('AF', 'AX', 'AL', 'DZ', 'AS', 'AD', 'AO', 
    'AI', 'AQ', 'AG', 'AR', 'AM', 'AW', 'AU', 'AT', 'AZ', 'BS', 'BH', 'BD', 
    'BB', 'BY', 'BE', 'BZ', 'BJ', 'BM', 'BT', 'BO', 'BQ', 'BA', 'BW', 'BV', 
    'BR', 'IO', 'BN', 'BG', 'BF', 'BI', 'KH', 'CM', 'CA', 'CV', 'KY', 'CF', 
    'TD', 'CL', 'CN', 'CX', 'CC', 'CO', 'KM', 'CG', 'CD', 'CK', 'CR', 'CI', 
    'HR', 'CU', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DJ', 'DM', 'DO', 'EC', 'EG', 'SV', 
    'GQ', 'ER', 'EE', 'ET', 'FK', 'FO', 'FJ', 'FI', 'FR', 'GF', 'PF', 'TF', 
    'GA', 'GM', 'GE', 'DE', 'GH', 'GI', 'GR', 'GL', 'GD', 'GP', 'GU', 'GT', 
    'GG', 'GN', 'GW', 'GY', 'HT', 'HM', 'VA', 'HN', 'HK', 'HU', 'IS', 'IN', 
    'ID', 'IR', 'IQ', 'IE', 'IM', 'IL', 'IT', 'JM', 'JP', 'JE', 'JO', 'KZ', 
    'KE', 'KI', 'KP', 'KR', 'KW', 'KG', 'LA', 'LV', 'LB', 'LS', 'LR', 'LY',
    'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'MO', 'MK', 'MG', 'MW', 'MY', 'MV', 'ML', 'MT', 'MH',
    'MQ', 'MR', 'MU', 'YT', 'MX', 'FM', 'MD', 'MC', 'MN', 'ME', 'MS', 'MA', 
    'MZ', 'MM', 'NA', 'NR', 'NP', 'NL', 'NC', 'NZ', 'NI', 'NE', 'NG', 'NU', 
    'NF', 'MP', 'NO', 'OM', 'PK', 'PW', 'PS', 'PA', 'PG', 'PY', 'PE', 'PH', 
    'PN', 'PL', 'PT', 'PR', 'QA', 'RE', 'RO', 'RU', 'RW', 'BL', 'SH', 'KN', 
    'LC', 'MF', 'PM', 'VC', 'WS', 'SM', 'ST', 'SA', 'SN', 'RS', 'SC', 'SL', 
    'SG', 'SX', 'SK', 'SI', 'SB', 'SO', 'ZA', 'GS', 'SS', 'ES', 'LK', 'SD', 
    'SR', 'SJ', 'SZ', 'SE', 'CH', 'SY', 'TW', 'TJ', 'TZ', 'TH', 'TL', 'TG', 
    'TK', 'TO', 'TT', 'TN', 'TR', 'TM', 'TC', 'TV', 'UG', 'UA', 'AE', 'GB', 
    'US', 'UM', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VU', 'VE', 'VN', 'VG', 'VI', 'WF', 'EH', 'YE', 
    'ZM', 'ZW');

    $ISO3166 = NULL;
    //Loop all country codes
    foreach ($countrycode_list as $countrycode) {
        $locale_cc = Locale::getDisplayRegion('-' . $countrycode, 
        $countrySelection);

        if (strcasecmp($country_name, $locale_cc) == 0) {
            $ISO3166 = $countrycode;
            break;
        }
    }
//return NULL if not found or country code
return $ISO3166;
}

}
?>
```

Comment: I can't allow multiple selections in the form

Comment: I changed it. It should still work just fine. Try it.

Comment: Where is the text from the option tag in your given solution?

Answer (score 2):

Change the values in JS when the form is submitted
OR
Change the value to:

```
<option value="CG_Congo">Congo</option>
```

and then split it using explode or split

```
$location = explode("_", $_POST["country_code"]);
```

OR Save it in a DB and query OR
Save an array in your code with the translations:

```
$translations = ['CG' => "Congo", etc];
```

Would really not recommend the last one however.
I don't see why wouldn't you change the option value as you still get the country code but the country name as an addition.

Edit: Found a JSON country name list online: http://country.io/names.json,
You can do something like this:

```
$country_code_to_name = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://country.io/names.json"), true);
echo $country_code_to_name[$_POST["country_code"]];
```

Comment: This is a long list that change from time to time. There will be other lists also for cities etc', so I can't change values.

Comment: Added another option.