# Get array key and value on other pages

Tags: php, arrays, post

This is reservation.php file:

[image]

And this is the checkout.php file code:

[image]

I cannot print the selected option value to the page. Just selected array key is printed.

Comment: Please share your code instead of screenshot.

Comment: That's how select option works. You'll get what's in `value`, not what's shown to the user. This question is quite similar: [Get Text From Option Tag in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767748/get-text-from-option-tag-in-php)

Comment: Is there no way to get this array's value on other pages? when I use $_POST['transferTypes'] code it's print array key just selected option...

Answer (score 0):

Select option will only return the "value".
Since there is no use of the array key (based on your code), just do like this:

```
echo "<option value='$transferName'>$transferName</option>";
```

this way you can get the transfer name instead of the key.

Comment: Yes, already used it. But how about both transfer key and value ?!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this.

One of the ***intuitive*** ways is to combine both key and string into one single string, with the "special" string/token at the middle to split these values.

For example,

```
"aaa" => "bbb"
```

Then you can combine both of these, such as "**aaa::bbb**", with "**::**" as the splitter at the middle. You can use [explode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate the key & value inside ***checkout.php*** file.

**reservation.php**

```
<form action="checkout.php" method="post">
    <select name="transferTypes" id="transferTypes" required>
    <?php
        $transferTypes = array(
            "aaa" => "bbb",
            "ccc" => "ddd"
        );
        echo "<option value='' selected disable>yadayadayada .. </option>";
        foreach($transferTypes as $transferKey => $transferName) {

            $combine = $transferKey . "::" . $transferName; // combine key::value here

            echo "<option value='$combine'>$transferName</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**checkout.php**

```
<?php
    list($key, $value) = explode("::" , $_POST['transferTypes']);
    echo "Key : " . $key . "<br>";
    echo "Value : " . $value . "<br>";
?>
```

Please note that this method isn't anywhere clean, but then it can accomplish the job right?

Another way is to separate the `$transferTypes` into a new file, include it to your ***reservation.php*** and ***checkout.php***, then do the [array_search()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the key. If I'm at your side, I'll do the latter way.