# Getting option text instead of value

Tags: php, laravel

Is that possible to get option `text` instead of `value`?

Somehow I need to use same option for 2 purpose. one of them need to get value which will be `id` of selected option and for another purpose i need to get `text` of that option.

here is how it looks like in `HTML`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="address_id">
  <option value="1">Street 3.</option>
  <option value="2">Street 4.</option>
</select>
```

I saw solutions base on `Jquery` and `JavaScript` but that's not gonna work for me I need `PHP` solution.

here is my saving method:

```
// codes....
$order->address = $request->input('address_id'); // basically will save value
//codes...
Auth::user()->orders()->save($order); //saving
```

Comment: that is not sent to the server, so you cant with php, not that you should need to. either `<option value="Street 3">Street 3.</option>` or you will know the, id to street, relationship from when you generated the select list in the first place

Comment: The value is what is sent to the server - the text is not. What do you mean js won't work for you. Are you creating the form? In your PHP can you just reverse engineer the text that was in that option?

Comment: any idea how can i achieve that?

Comment: @JasonB the only reason i say js not work for me is that if i use js then later when i need to get value for my other purpose will not work then. that's why.

Comment: @rtfm well your solution is not that good bro cause as i said for my other purpose i will need that id as value.

Comment: 2 solutions, the latter will work of you dont like the former

Comment: Refer this link for solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767748/get-text-from-option-tag-in-php

Comment: Solutiin is solution