# How to print a form data insted their value?

Tags: php, wordpress

I trying to print a form data with a shortcode but the code is printing their value

I have a Wordpress site that I need to print a form data with a shortcode, but the system is printing their value instead. The first block is my form. Second block is my shortcode content.

```
<div class="cidade">
<form action="" method="post">
    <select id="cidade2" name="cidade" onchange="submit();">
        <option value="augustopestana-rd2">Augusto Pestana</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>

<?php echo $_POST['cidade']; ?>
```

And finally I past the shortcode into a wordpress widget expeting to print "Augusto Pestana" but it's printing "augustopestana-rd2".

Comment: You explicitly set the value to augustopestana-rd2. Either remove that attribute altogether which will then submit the values option text or change it to be Augusto Pestana explicitly.

Comment: Do I close with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767748/get-text-from-option-tag-using-php  Surely the answer isn't as simple as reversing the values.

Comment: If you use option tag with value it will take your value from attribute, please remove value attribute if you want to print the value.