# Select Option inside value with php

Tags: php, html-select

I have a trouble about select option value choosing with PHP

Multiple select box is showing for state and city. Jquery loads as ajax method for database. And I need to reach "option value" inside value. I will show the problem inside below codes.

```
   <?php  
     function load_country() {

     include 'includes/db.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ilce ORDER BY name";

    mysqli_set_charset($con, "UTF8");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $output .= '<option name="' . $row['name'] .'" value="' . 
      $row["ilce_id"].'">' . $row["name"]. '</option>';
    }

    return $output;

   }
  ?>

   <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state">
     <option>Choose State</option>
      <?php
        echo load_country();
      ?>
    </select>

    <?php 
      $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']);  
      echo $state;

     ?>

 <option value="5">New York</option>
 $state is showing for me Example : "id" => 5
```

Thus, I want to reach "New York", inside value.
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: The content of an `<option>` element is not posted to the server, only its `value`. I suggest referencing the names from the database by their IDs. Alternatively, set the `value` to the row's `name` instead of its `ilce_id`.

Comment: Well if you're wanting to get the value (5) of "New York" when it's selected and you're using jQuery, you can get that with `$("selector").val()`. "New York" can be retrieved with `$("selector").html()`

Comment: it is not working any solution. I cannot set value as "name" because I am using relative database. Then, every value HAS WILL BE changed. @David you are saying use with jquery. But I have to Add this value inside database with php

Comment: looks like you're vulnerable to persistent XSS here. pretty sure that line should read ```$output .= '<option name="' . htmlentities(urlencode($row['name'])) .'" value="' . 
      htmlentities(urlencode($row["ilce_id"])).'">' . htmlentities($row["name"]). '</option>';```  ... unless you store your data pre-htmlencoded in your database? (which is possible but unusual)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text content of an `<option>` element is not posted to the server, only its `value`.

If you're inserting the selected state into a database (like in a user table), you might just insert the numeric state ID and join the two tables when you need to display the information.

Alternatively, you can fetch an array of all states indexed by their IDs and then reference that array:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $allStates[$row['ilce_id']] = $row['name'];
}

$stateId = $_POST['state'];
$thisState = $allStates[$stateId];
echo $thisState;
```

Or just fetch the one row that you need by its ID, depending on what you need.

---

A less desirable solution is to set the `<option>` `value` to the row's name rather than its ID:

```
$output .= '<option value="' . $row["name"] . '">' . $row["name"] . '</option>';
```

But that seems to defeat the purpose of using a relational database.

---

Also see [Get Text From  Tag Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767748/get-text-from-option-tag-using-php).